# SQL Most Recent Variables for all IDs

Tags: sql, ssms

System has approximately 150 Sensors, trying to query for the most recent updated row for all sensors - so rows in query = number of SensorIDs in DB. Code below isn't operating as intended because MAX Variable for V1/V2/V3/Lat/Long isn't the most recent, it's the maximum value across all updates. Just looking for help to find most recent for those variables.

Max_Timestamp works for finding the most recent just not sure how to get the variables for that specific row exactly.

```
SELECT [SensorId]
      ,MAX(TimeStamp) AS MAX_Timestamp /* Most recent Occurence */
      ,MAX(Description) AS MAX_Description /*Doesn't change*/
      ,MAX(Type) AS MAX_Type /*Doesn't Change*/
      ,MAX(V1) AS MAX_V1 /*Need most recent variable not MAX*/
      ,MAX(V2) AS MAX_V2 /*Need most recent variable not MAX*/
      ,MAX(V3) AS MAX_V3 /*Need most recent variable not MAX*/
      ,MAX(Latitude) AS MAX_Lat /*Need most recent variable not MAX*/
      ,MAX(Longitude) AS MAX_Long /*Need most recent variable not MAX*
  FROM [IoTDB].[dbo].[IOT]
  GROUP BY SensorId
  ORDER BY SensorId
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? Tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Just updated it's SSMS, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Sql Server supports the `TOP(1) WITH TIES` feature

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES [SensorId]
      ,Timestamp 
      ,Description 
      ,Type 
      ,V1 
      ,V2 
      ,V3 
      ,Latitude
      ,Longitude
  FROM [IoTDB].[dbo].[IOT]
  ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by SensorId order by Timestamp desc);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, was completely unaware of with ties. Thanks Serg!

Comment: @MacDev . . . This construct (`TOP (1) WITH TIES` with `ROW_NUMBER()` in the `ORDER BY`) is quite convenient.  Do note that it is generally not the most performant solution.  In many cases, convenience is as or more important than raw performance, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to break it down into two operations:

Find the most recent occurence using MAX(TimeStamp) and store it in a temp table:

```
SELECT [SensorId]
      ,MAX(TimeStamp) AS MAX_Timestamp /* Most recent Occurence */
  INTO #mostRecentOccurence
  FROM [IoTDB].[dbo].[IOT]
  GROUP BY SensorId
```

JOIN this back to the original table:

```
SELECT iot.[SensorId]
      ,mr.MAX_Timestamp 
      ,iot.Description AS MAX_Description 
      ,iot.Type AS MAX_Type 
      ,iot.V1 AS MAX_V1 
      ,iot.V2 AS MAX_V2 
      ,iot.V3 AS MAX_V3 
      ,iot.Latitude AS MAX_Lat 
      ,iot.Longitude AS MAX_Long   
  FROM [IoTDB].[dbo].[IOT] iot
       INNER JOIN #mostRecentOccurence mr ON iot.SensorId = mr.SensorId
                                            AND iot.TimeStamp = mr.MAX_Timestamp
  ORDER BY iot.SensorId
```